# Dependabot from Github is telling me to update the gopkg.in/yaml.v2

Tags: go, dependencies, linter

I currently have gopkg.in/yaml.v2 < 2.2.8. What are the commands I need to execute on the terminal to properly update gopkg.in/yaml.v2?

I tried the following:

```
go get -u gopkg.in/yaml.v2@v2.4.0
```

But my CI checks are failing at the linter level.

The error is:

```
ERROR - changes: M go.mod M vendor/modules.txt ERROR: 2
```

Comment: Stop using gopkg.in. Use the real upstream like github.com/go-yaml/yaml. Read how to use modules.

Comment: @Volker, go-yaml uses gopkg.in in its go.mod. `go get ` is as suggested by go-yaml.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `go mod tidy` to cleanup go.mod after the `go get`